# RFC - safe enum in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, enums, enumeration

Morning all

Since the dawn of time, man has wished for and invented ways to do enumerations in Flash AS3.

There's been various problems with many attempts, such as the ability to use a constructor to create new types of the enum (insecure).

I believe the following is type-safe at compile time, and safe from being able to create new instances of the enum class at runtime.

The main issue surrounds the inability in AS3 to have a private constructor. In this example, the constructor can only succeed if passed the private static const variable ENFORCER, which is only visible inside of the class.

```
package
{
    public class PermissionsEnum
    {

        private static const ENFORCER = new Object();

        public static const READ:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 1);
        public static const WRITE:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 2);
        public static const CREATE:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 4);
        public static const DELETE:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 8);

        private var _value:uint;

        public function PermissionsEnum(e:Object, v:uint)
        {
            if (e != ENFORCER)
                throw new Error("Attempted enum security breach.");

            this._value = v;
        }

        public function get value() : uint
        {
            return this._value;
        }

    }

}
```

Comments anyone?

Other previous attempts have allowed some sort of circluar reference thing (which incidentally, the Java compiler disallows, and the C# compiler allows) as an attempt to disallow the runtime creation of more enum values. I think this is more beautiful though.

What do we think?

Rich

Comment: Why not simply use a private constructor and do away with `ENFORCER` object and the runtime security check?

Comment: PermissionsEnum.as, Line 16 1153: A constructor can only be declared public.

Comment: Amn, that is entire reason for this (and all prior) flash enum discussions. There is no private constructor facility.

Comment: I see. Truth be said, I come from `haXe` background, which does have private constructors, I naturally thought ActionScript 3 does too. My bad, sorry for wasting your time. Both languages (compilers, actually) compile SWF files, you see. With what you have, it seems you have a very clean and neat strategy, in fact, it's rather ingenious, in my humble opinion :)

Comment: Thanks :-) I'm going to post the completed one here shortly as an answer. Cus of my lack of rep, I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can use more strict compile time restrictions in constructor (all the following code is in the same `PermissionsEnum.as` file):

```
package
{
public class PermissionsEnum
{

    private static const ENFORCER:Enforcer = new Enforcer();

    public static const READ:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 1);
    public static const WRITE:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 2);
    public static const CREATE:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 4);
    public static const DELETE:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 8);

    private var _value:uint;

    public function PermissionsEnum(e:Enforcer, v:uint)
    {
        this._value = v;
    }

    public function get value() : uint
    {
        return this._value;
    }

}
}

class Enforcer
{
}
```

Comment: A good point, and I raise you this:

private static const ENFORCER = new PermissionsEnum(null, 0);
  
public function PermissionsEnum(e:PermissionsEnum, v:uint)
{
 if (e != ENFORCER)
  throw new Error("Attempted enum security breach.");
 this._value = v;
}
  

}
}

So at static initialisation time, ENFORCER is null. The constructor succeeds because it is comparing (null == null), and then the ENFORCER pointer is updated with the new instance of PermissionsEnum.

More elegent as now there is no need for the separate class Enforcer?

Rich

Comment: Sorry its not clear, but I cannot answer my own post for another 7 hours.

Comment: But anyway your solution relies on runtime exception. I can just declare a value without initializing (`var enumToInit: PermissionsEnum;` — it will be null) and pass it ti constructor and compiler says nothing. My solution doesn't allow create new instance at compile time which is better for enums.

Comment: Constantiner, I put that code in CS5 and it didn't work. Can you try it?

Comment: @RichColours Have you runtime exception? It seems ActionScript has problems with implementation of this related to initialization :( So +1 for your implementation.

Comment: Yes there is a runtime error.
public var test:PermsEnum; // works, obviously test is null
public var test:PermsEnum = PermsEnum.CREATE; // program starts, but during the static initialisation of PermsEnum, TypeError is thrown:

TypeError: Error #1115: PermsEnum.as$224::Enforcer is not a constructor.
 at PermsEnum$cinit()

(i renamed the file ...)

Answer (score 0):

1) What about converting values to enum members?

2) I see one problem in creating `PermissionsEnum`: there's no common control over its inner value. I mean, if I've got 5-10 members in enum, there's no trouble to find duplicated values. But if the list grows, the chance to make a mistake in source drows too:

```
public static const READ:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 1);
public static const WRITE:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 7);
public static const APPEND:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 15);
public static const CREATE:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 8);
public static const DELETE:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 3);
public static const COMMIT:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 6);
public static const SUBMIT:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 21);
public static const POP:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 22);
public static const PUSH:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 3);
public static const SELECT:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 17);
public static const DESELECT:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 22);
public static const END:PermissionsEnum = new PermissionsEnum(ENFORCER, 15);
```

Comment: 2) These values can't be created outside class. So you control and debug them once at the stage of creating class.

Comment: Hi Moropus

The problem i'm trying to solve is the problem of the "cannot have private constructor".

Constantiner is right. As the class developer, you are in control of what code you right. The consumer of the class is the entity that cannot be trusted, and thus should not be able to freely initialise enumeration instances.

Comment: Re 1) - make yourself a public function fromValue(whatever) : PermissionsEnum. Done.

Comment: 2) Yes, I know. But I want something, that will make changes more safe (that will save my code from me). If you look throught the list in my answer a couple of times you will notice that some values are duplicated - and it's not obvious even with one dozen of items! That's what I mean.

Comment: Hmm, at compile-time ... guess we might have to wait for Adobe to release a proper language, with modern OO ;-)